# click needs to finish before activating again

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm working on a simple sort of slideshow with next and previous buttons to navigate.

The way I set this up is having a container with 7 slides in it that all have the same size as the container and with with left are positioned 100%, 200%, etc.

The buttons animate the marginLeft to go to the next or previous slide.

```
$('#slideArrowRight').click(function(){
        var allSlides = $(this).siblings('.slideContainer');
        var slideWidth = allSlides.width();
        var maxSlides = $('.slideContainer').length - 1;
        var maxWidth = maxSlides * slideWidth;
        var negative = 0 - maxWidth;

        if (parseFloat($(allSlides).css('marginLeft')) <= negative) {}
        else {      $(allSlides).animate({marginLeft: "-=" + (slideWidth) + "px"}, {duration:200});        }

    });
```

I'm using an if statement to check if the maximum amount of marginLeft is reached so it can't go further.

That's what I came up with. and gues what the thing actually works xD
(pretty new to javascript and jQuery so yeah i get exited if stuff starts working)

But if I click the buttons really fast, it gets pased the last slide as the function stacks in the queue. and the maximum marginLeft is not reached at the moment of the click.

So my question is how can i get it so that the function can not run except if the function is finished?

I try'd .finish() but that instantly cancels the animation and is not what I'm looking for. i mainly want it so that the function can not execute unless the function is not in the queue.

Comment: I have a demo that sounds the same on your requirements buddy. [**Click here**](http://anthonypagaycarbon.iblogger.org/), If it is then I'll give the code to you. Just hover the banner the you will see what I mean.

Comment: it is the same idea but with next and previous buttons instead of the thumbnails

Comment: Do you want to delay next "click" event before first is finished? Or do you want to cancel next "click" events when first is executing right now?

Comment: preventing clicks would be a nicer solution i think. so i would go for the delay next click option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use simple flag `animationUnderExecution` which is set to `true` at the beginning of the function and set to `false` at the end.

First of all define flag before event function:

```
var animationUnderExecution = false;
```

Now inside your function (at the beginning) check if you are executing another animation and set flag to true:

```
if (animationUnderExecution) return;
animationUnderExecution = true;
```

Now you have to set flag to false when animation is finished:

```
$(allSlides)
    .animate({marginLeft: "-=" + (slideWidth) + "px"}, 
        {duration:200},
        complete: function() {
            animationUnderExecution = false;
    });
```

Summary it should look as following:

```
var animationUnderExecution = false;
$('#slideArrowRight').click(function(){

        if (animationUnderExecution) return;
        animationUnderExecution = true;

        var allSlides = $(this).siblings('.slideContainer');
        var slideWidth = allSlides.width();
        var maxSlides = $('.slideContainer').length - 1;
        var maxWidth = maxSlides * slideWidth;
        var negative = 0 - maxWidth;

        if (parseFloat($(allSlides).css('marginLeft')) <= negative) {}
        else {      
            $(allSlides)
              .animate({marginLeft: "-=" + (slideWidth) + "px"},  
                  {duration:200},
                  complete: function() {
                      animationUnderExecution = false;
                });
        }

    });
```

Comment: ah yes i understand the principle, but as i test it. It will only let me animate once

    .complete( function() {

uncaught typeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Ach i made a mistake. `complete` is another attribute of `animate` function. I've updated my code.

Comment: ok found the last syntax error, complete and duration go in the same bracket. and did some testing and this works completly now